# Why are angels opposed to Sam using his powers?

Tags: supernatural

In Supernatural season 4 episodes, why are angels opposed to Sam using his powers to remove demons from human bodies so they can be sent back to hell?

Comment: Because the powers are fueled by demon blood and demonic/dark in nature.

Answer (score 2):

Sam's powers are Demonic and are a result of his status as Lucifer's Perfect Host.  The more he uses them, the farther down the dark path he would be drawn.  This is borne out by the story, as Sam eventually ends up addicted to Demon blood with little self control to enhance his powers.

Answer (score 0):

I think its deeper than that. The angels have proved before they will do whatever it takes even if it means being evil.

I think its because they know if Sam continued, eventually he will he able to do the same to angels.